# Adding elements of multiple arrays together in swift 4

Tags: arrays, swift, sum, closures

Is there a way to add elements of multiple arrays together in swift, without for loops?

For the instance of 3 arrays:

```
let arrayA: [Float] = [1,2,3,4]
let arrayB: [Float] = [10,20,30,40]
let arrayB: [Float] = [100,200,300,400]
```

I'm looking for an output of [111,222,333,444]

I know this can be accomplished with two arrays through the following methods

```
let arrayResult:[Float] = zip(arrayA,arrayB).map() {$0 + $1}
```

or

```
let arrayResult:[Float] = zip(arrayA,arrayB).map(+)
```

Thank you

Comment: Both of your examples don't use for loops. What more are you looking for?

Comment: @MikeTaverne he needs it for 3 arrays not 2

Comment: Good point, didn't read the question carefully.